# What font is this? Whatfont , fontsquierrel, doesnt work*

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

Sorry for the lame question, but I can't figure out what font is used in image below?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Be sure to take a look at the [requirements for font identification questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366).

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is [Nordique Pro Regular](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/leksen-design/nordique-pro)

[image: Nordique Pro Regular]

Comment: very good, but don't post just a link, add a screenshot of the font so people can compare without having to click the link (and if the link dies, we still have the image)

Comment: I added a screenshot for you, but please do add an image in future as Luciano said.

Comment: @BrunoBispo if you want to recreate the exact look of the font you posted above, you'll need to reduce the kerning a little bit. Depending on what application you're using your font in, there are different ways to do that. If you need help, just let us know!